Recurrences on tiling
THE QUESTION
Given a 2 × 2 tile and seven dominoes (2 × 1 tile), find the number of ways of tiling (that is, cover without leaving
gaps and without overlapping of any two tiles) a 2 × 7 rectangle using some of these tiles.
My approach:
I used recurrence relation to solve this
let us take no of ways of tiling $2*n$ be $a_n$
then $a_1=1,a_2=3,a_3=5...$ and goes on.The general relation which I got is
$$a_n=2a_{n-2} +a_{n-1}$$
then if I use this and did for $a_7$ I am getting the answer as 85.
MY DOUBT But the answer is 59. Where am I going wrong? (Is my general formula for this case wrong?)

$2a_(n-2) $ means 2a subscript n-2

Source: IOQM 2023. Apparently some solutions on the internet have made the same mistake

A solution is available on AopS

Yes, your general formula is wrong, and unless you specify how you arrived at it, we cannot help you.

Correct formula would be $$a_n = a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$$ where $f_n$ stand for the number of tilings of table $2\times n$ with dominoes $2\times 1$.  So $$f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$$
Since $f_n$ is
$1,2,3, 5,  8, 13,..$ we have $a_n: 1,3,5,10, 18, 33,59... $

can u say how did u derive the general formula for f(n) also for a(n)

Search for fibonaccy sequence in web.

ok for $a_n $ how did u derive,what is wrong in my formula

ou can't use a_n if you used the only 2x2 table
